# Access 2010 table query

Tags: database, ms-access

I have a very basic Access 2010 database  of which I have 45 individual tables for the past 45 years which has the fields: date, book title, subject, cost, stock qty and notes.  I then appended all the data into one master table of the exact same design which updated automatically whenever I edited a record in the individual tables.  Now it has stopped updating.  So basically all I want is an master table that updates whenever I change a record in the the individual tables.

Comment: Why do you still have the individual tables? Why not just have the master table? How are you doing the updating? What specifically is not working?

Comment: I need to look at the individual year tables for quickness and printing but when i type any alterations they don't change in so called 'master' table.

Comment: It sounds like you need a query instead of different tables. You can even edit data in a simple query like this. Then you solve all solve all you sync issues and simplify everything.

Comment: @Brad gave you the answer. Archive the 45(!) tables and continue with the single table.